# Is there a way to detect programming code inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Like I wrote above I'm looking for a RegEx to detect code inside a `textarea` so for example:

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

With detecting code I mean every single programming language or CSS or whatever exists on this planet. Maybe there is a RegEx or something else?

Comment: Do you mean you want to detect all the languages (on this planet)?

Comment: Why limit it to the planet?

Comment: I would look at the syntax highlighting libraries out there and see what they do. Some have auto detection.

Comment: Look at CodeMirror.

Comment: @epascarello Interesting question. You are absolutely right. We should expand this!

Comment: @Mr.Jo Are you working on syntax-highlighting?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW No, I'm working with a plain text contenteditable div and I want to wrap code into a special designed div

Comment: @Mr.Jo I am currently working on an IDE, and I wanted to collab with you. That's why I asked you that question.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW Ah interesting. Write me on Skype Jaika113. I'll answer later if its ok

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect all the programming languages with one RegEx.
But you can detect one language. For example, here is a regular expression to detect some HTML code:

```
let myRegularExpression = new RegExp(/<\s*.*>/ig);
```

Here is your code:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].addEventListener("keyup", function() {
   let myRegularExpression = new RegExp(/<\s*.*>/ig);
   if(myRegularExpression.test(this.value)) {
      alert("That's HTML!");
   }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

For JavaScript, use this regular expression (to detect variables):

```
let myRegularExpression = new RegExp(/var\s*.*;/g);
```

Here is your code:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].addEventListener("keyup", function() {
   let myRegularExpression = new RegExp(/var\s*.*;/g);
   if(myRegularExpression.test(this.value)) {
      alert("That's JavaScript!");
   }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

You can also check some libraries if you're looking at syntax highlighting like [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/), [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/), [Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) or [ACE](https://ace.c9.io/) and look at their code!